# How to edit embed discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to edit embed:

```
    day_msg = {} #I am creating this variable out of function.
    chat = client.get_channel(1007301750895677491)
    embed = discord.Embed(
            color=discord.Color.green()
        )
    file = discord.File("result.png", filename="image.png")
    embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
    if issent_day == 0:
      day_msg = await chat.send(file=file, embed=embed)
      issent_day = 1
    else:
      await day_msg.edit(file=file, embed=embed)
```

I need to send 1 message and than edit it so i used issent_day variable. But when i am

```
trying to edit it i am getting error:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-15' coro=<day_vipe() done, defined at main.py:290> exception=TypeError('Object of type File is not JSON serializable')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 321, in day_vipe
    await day_msg.edit(file=file, embed=embed)
  File "/home/runner/Stump/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/message.py", line 1111, in edit
    data = await self._state.http.edit_message(self.channel.id, self.id, **fields)
  File "/home/runner/Stump/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 156, in request
    kwargs['data'] = utils.to_json(kwargs.pop('json'))
  File "/home/runner/Stump/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/utils.py", line 328, in to_json
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=True)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type File is not JSON serializable
```

may be a problem with day_msg variable. I am creating this variable out of function. but i reaaly dont know.

Comment: You can't edit the file once sent.

Comment: But i am trying to edit embed with file. Not just file

Comment: yeah but that doesn't work once sent

Comment: You can't change the file. https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit